# How can I compile an APK from a GitHub source

Tags: android, apk

I want to build an APK from this GitHub repository:
https://github.com/SDLash3D/cs16-client/
How can I do it? (Please mention the name of the apps required (preferably for Windows) and the process)

Comment: I think you should ask that in issues section in the project.

Comment: I have already done that. But the developer said that for now the built apk is issued to beta testers only. Others have to figure out how to build it on their own. The full product will be available to everyone in the spring.

Answer (score 5):

To make a apk from this repo downlad android folder using git or any tool that you prefer.

And open android studio if don't have this down download it from this link

If you don't have the android sdk with you then download android studio bundle

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

For this you will need jdk . If you don't have this dowload it and install it.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

And add the jdk path as JAVA_HOME in environmental variable.

And install your android studio.

Then open the android studio and import downladed repo earlier.

Android studio will resolve the dependencies and after all is done you can build an apk from it.

You can get the apk from the app-build-output-apk folder.

Comment: If you would take a look at github, the author of this project used strange makefiles-based build system. I'm not sure Android Studio would work with that.

Comment: Probably not, you'll have to find a way for it to build with Gradle or use Eclipse for compiling. Anyway would be a headache...

Comment: That's because this source is of a project that is to be built in a full Android OS source tree (lots of related projects). You can't build it alone. I see that from the Android.mk and CM*  files... You probably need to look at how to build CyanogenMod. Won't work on Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Running `~/buildAPKs/build.github.bash https://github.com/SDLash3D/` will attempt to build APKs from all the AndroidManifest.xml files it finds at this GitHub account.

As https://github.com/SDLash3D/ currently has no AndroidManifest.xml files to build from, try `~/buildAPKs/build.github.bash https://github.com/BuildAPKs` which should build many APKs for you from GitHub in Android on handheld as well as in Windows.